# Updating KnockoutJS associative observableArray values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, associative-array

This should be really simple.

I have an associative observable array with a name and a boolean value.

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "name1", boolVal: true },
    { name: "name2", boolVal: true },
]);
```

Then a simple function to change boolVal.

```
this.changeValue = function (item) {
    item.boolVal = false;
};
```

When I call the changeValue function, boolVal does change (see console.log(data) in my jsfiddle) but the view doesn't update. The value on the screen remains "true". I must be making an incorrect assumption regarding how KnockoutJS works.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gBLAy/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to the KO update UI you need to have observable properties:

```
this.items = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "name1", boolVal: ko.observable(true) },
    { name: "name2", boolVal: ko.observable(true) },
]);
```

And set it with:

```
this.changeValue = function (item) {
    item.boolVal(false);
};
```

The `ko.observableArray` only tracks item addition and removal. So it won't notify the UI if one of its items changed. For that you need to have `ko.observable` on the items.

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HcXPB/)

Comment: Didn't think of that, but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question about having an "associative" array be observable.  This is only a standard array.